how come motion component in framer motion start with lowercase?
I learned that React component names should start with a lowercase letter so that they can differentiate between custom components and inbuilt HTML components
how come motion.div in the Framer motion component starts with lowercase.
although I do understand that it is accessing div property on motion object, but I was guessing that lowercase thing should kick in before evaluating that expression while JSX is being compiled / translated to JS.
I am guessing there is some gap in my understanding here, please help.

This is an interesting question. While it is true that lowercase JSX would be treated as HTML elements, when transpiling JSX to React.createElement, it will analyse and parse into an AST tree.
When it encounters an Identifier, it will be converted into string but will keep it as it is for member expression.
In the case of motion.div, it is a member expression so it will not be treated as HTML elements and work as intended.
Reference (Babel for example): https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/a8994f8b7d421dd17b076c2557c9d5bd0e3faef1/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/src/create-plugin.ts#L406-L411

thanks for sharing the code as well. I will see if I can make sense of it :P
